# Send acf_form() through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This function from my web-site:

```
    acf_form(array(
        'post_id'       => 'new_post',
        'post_content'  => false,
        'new_post'      => array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        ),
        'submit_value'  => 'Опубликовать'
    ));
    ?>
```

This works on the [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/) plugin for WordPress and generates form to create new post. How sent this form through Ajax without page refresh???

Answer (score 0):

User acf form head before calling `acf_form`:

```
// will enqueue all ACF related scripts and styles for the form to display correctly. 
acf_form_head();

acf_form(array(
        'post_id'       => 'new_post',
        'post_content'  => false,
        'new_post'      => array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        ),
        'submit_value'  => 'Опубликовать'
    ));
```